# To make array identical by swapping elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

There are 2 i/p array's. They are identical when they have exactly same numbers in it. To make them identical, we can swap their elements. Swapping will have cost. If we are swapping a and b elements then cost = min(a, b).

While making array's identical, cost should be minimum.
If it is not possible to make array identical then print -1.

```
i/p:     
3 6 6 2  
2 7 7 3   

o/p :     
4
```

Here I have swapped (2,7) and (2,6). So min Cost = 2 + 2 = 4.

Logic :

1. Make 2 maps which will store frequency of i/p array's elements.
2. if element "a" in aMap is also present in bMap, then we have to consider number of swapping for a = abs(freq(a) in aMap - freq(a) in bMap)
3. if frequency of elements is "odd", then not possible to make them identical.
4. else , add total swaps from both maps and find cost using
   cost = smallest element * total swaps

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int size;
        long long int cost = 0;
        cin >> size;
        bool flag = false;
        map<long long int, int> aMap;
        map<long long int, int> bMap;
        
        // storing frequency of elements of 1st input array in map
        for( int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
        {
            long long int no;
            cin >> no;
            aMap[no]++;
        }

        // storing frequency of elements of 2nd input array in map
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
        {
            long long int no;
            cin >> no;
            bMap[no]++;
        }

        // fetching smallest element (i.e. 1st element) from both map
        long long int firstNo = aMap.begin()->first;
        long long int secondNo = bMap.begin()->first;
        long long int smallestNo;
       
        // finding smallest element from both maps
        if(firstNo < secondNo)
            smallestNo = firstNo;
        else
            smallestNo = secondNo;

        map<long long int, int> :: iterator itr;

        // trying to find out total number of swaps we have to perform
        int totalSwapsFromA = 0;
        int totalSwapsFromB = 0;

        // trversing a map
        for(itr = aMap.begin(); itr != aMap.end(); itr++)
        {
            // if element "a" in aMap is also present in bMap, then we have to consider
            // number of swapping = abs(freq(a) in aMap - freq(a) in bMap)
            auto newItr = bMap.find(itr->first);
            if(newItr != bMap.end())
            {
                if(itr->second >= newItr->second)
                {
                    itr->second -= newItr->second;
                    newItr->second = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    newItr->second -= itr->second;
                    itr->second = 0;   
                }                        
            }
            // if freq is "odd" then, this input is invalid as it can not be swapped
            if(itr->second & 1 )
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // if freq is even, then we need to swap only for freq(a)/ 2 times
                itr->second /= 2;

                // if swapping element is smallest element then we required 1 less swap
                if(itr->first == smallestNo && itr->second != 0)
                    totalSwapsFromA += itr->second -1;
                else
                    totalSwapsFromA += itr->second;
            }
            
        }  

        // traversing bMap to check whether there any number is present which is 
        // not in aMap.
      if(!flag)
      {
        for(itr = bMap.begin(); itr != bMap.end(); itr++)
        {
            auto newItr = aMap.find(itr->first);
            if( newItr == aMap.end())
            {
                // if frew is odd , then i/p is invalid
                if(itr->second & 1)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    itr->second /= 2;

                    // if swapping element is smallest element then we required 1 less swap
                    if(itr->first == smallestNo && itr->second != 0)
                        totalSwapsFromB += itr->second -1;
                    else
                        totalSwapsFromB += itr->second;
                    
                }
                
            }
        } 
     }
       if( !flag )
       {   
          cost = smallestNo * (totalSwapsFromB + totalSwapsFromA);
          cout<<"cost "<<cost <<endl;
       }
       else
           cout<<"-1"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No error in the above code but giving wrong answer and not getting accepted.
Can anyone improve this code / logic ?

Comment: do not use variable length arrays, `a[size]`and `n[size]` and `aHash[N]` and `bHash[N]`, even you compiler accept them (like g++) the used size at least because of N value is probably out of the size of the stack

Comment: Peculiar that just yesterday we had [Making Two Arrays Identical by swapping elements \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743678/making-two-arrays-identical-by-swapping-elements) :)

Comment: proper solution is swap `(6, 7)` so cost is `1`. I have no idea why your code is so complex. I think it is doable in 20 lines.

Comment: In `aHash[a[i]]` how can you suppose  `a[i]` is a valid index in *aHash* after `cin >> a[i];`? same in `bHash[b[i]]`

Comment: @MarekR  If we swap(6,7) then cost will be 6. ( cost = min( swapping element a, b ) )

Comment: @bruno I have taken enough large array. i.e. 2 * 10^ 6. Range is given in the question. Array is not going to go beyond that range.

Comment: that have no sense to have them in the stack, out of that if I enter 987654321 for `cin >> a[i];` etc you go out of your arrays doing `aHash[a[i]]`

Comment: @user1745866 But the above code is not getting accepted. What is the problem can you tell me what errors came up or what the expected output is?? What is the problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have 2 arrays:

```
A: 1 5 5
B: 1 4 4
```

We know that we want to move a 5 down and a 4 up, so we have to options: swapping 4 by 5 (with cost `min(4, 5) = 4`) or using the minimum element to do achive the same result, making 2 swaps:

```
A: 1 5 5   swap 1 by 4 (cost 1)
B: 1 4 4    
________
A: 4 5 5   swap 1 by 5 (cost 1)
B: 1 1 4
________
A: 4 1 5   total cost: 2
B: 5 1 4
```

So the question we do at every swap is this. Is it better to swap directly or swapping twice using the minimum element as pivot?

In a nutshell, let `m` be the minimum element in both arrays and you want to swap `i` for `j`. The cost of the swap will be

```
min( min(i,j), 2 * m )
```

So just find out all the swaps you need to do, apply this formula and sum the results to get your answer.

Comment: I have updated the code, and followed what you said. But still giving me wrong answer and not getting accepted. Am I missing any corner case ? ( code has no error and giving right answer for my inputs. )

Comment: Are you sure you are swapping the minimum number of elements possible? Are you sure you are handling correctly the cases where it is impossible to solve (which is when there is a number that appears an odd number of times)?

Answer (score 1):

For reducing the swap cost see Daniel's answer. For finding if the swap is actually possible, please do the following, the swaps are actually only possible if you have an even number of elements in total, so that you can split them out evenly, so if you have 2, 4 or 6 5's you are good, but if you have 1, 3, or 5 5's return -1. It is impossible if your number of duplicates of a number is odd. For actually solving the problem, there is a very simple solution I can think of, through it is a little bit expensive, you just need to make sure that there are the same number of elements on each side so the simple way to do that would be to declare a new array:

```
int temp[size of original arrays];
//Go through both arrays and store them in temp
```

Take half of each element, so something like:

```
int count[max element in array - min element in array];
for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
   count[temp[i]]++;
}
```

Take half of each element from temp. When you see an element that matches a element on your count array so whenever you see a 1 decrement the index on the count array by 1, so something like count[1]--; Assuming count starts at 0. If the index is at zero and the element is that one, that means a swap needs to be done, in this case find the next min in the other array and swap them. Albeit a little bit expensive, but it is the simplest way I can think of. So for example in your case:

```
i/p:     
3 6 6 2  
2 7 7 3   

o/p :     
4
```

We would need to store the min index as 2. Cause that is the smallest one. So we would have an array that looks like the following:

```
1 1 0 0 1 1
//one two one three zero four zero five 1 six and 1 seven
```

You would go through the first array, when you see the second six, your array index at 6 would be zero, so you know you need to swap it, you would find the min in the other array, which is 2 and then swap 6 with 2, after wards you can go through the array smoothly. Finally you go through the second array, afterwards when you see the last 7 it will look for the min on the other side swap them...., which is two, note that if you had 3 twos on one side and one two on the other, chances are the three twos will go to the other side, and 2 of them will come back, because we are always swapping the min, so there will always be an even number of ways we can rearrange the elements.

Answer (score 1):

@user1745866 You can simplify your task of determining the answer **-1** by using only variable:

let we have **int x=0** and we will just do **XOR** of all the i/p integers like this:

```
int x = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  cin>>a[i];
  x = x^a[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  cin>>b[i];
  x = x^b[i];
}

if(x!=0)
  cout<<-1;
else{
  ...do code for remain 2 condition...
}
```

Now the point is how it will work because , as all the numbers of both array should occurs only even number of times and when we do **XOR operation** of any number which occured even number of times we will get 0.... otherwise they can't be identical arrays.

Now for 2nd condition(which gives answer 0) you should use multimap so you would be able to directly compare both arrays in O(n) time complexity as if all elements of both arrays are same you can output:**0**

(**Notice:** i am suggesting multimap because 1:You would have both array sorted and all elements would be there means also duplicates.
2: because they are sorted, if they consist of same element at same position we can output:0 otherwise you have to proceed further for your 3rd condition or have to swap the elements.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem link  https://www.codechef.com/JULY20B/problems/CHFNSWPS

here for calculating minimum number of swap.we will having 2 cases

let say an example

```
l1=[1,2,2]
l2=[1,5,5]
```

**case 1. swap each pair wrt to min(l1,l2)=1**

step 1  swapping single 2 of a pair of 2 from l1-> [1,1,2]
[2,5,5] cost is 1
step 2 swapping single 5 of a pair of 5 from l1->  [1,5,2]
[2,1,5] cost is 1
total cost is 2

**case 2. swap min of l1 with max of l2(repeat until both list end)**

try to think if we sort 1st list in increasing order and other as decreasing order then we can minimize cost.

```
 l1=[1,2,2]
 l2=[5,5,1]
```

Trick is that we only need to store min(l1,l2) in variable say mn. Then remove all common element from both list.

```
now list became l1=[2,2]
                l2=[5,5]
```

then swap each element from index 0 to len(l1)-1 with jump of 2 like 0,2,4,6..... because each odd neighbour wiil be same as previous number.
after perform swapping cost will be 2 and

```
l1=[5,2]
l2=[2,5]  cost is 2
total cost is 2
```

Let say an other example

```
l1=[2,2,5,5]
l2=[3,3,4,4]
```

after solving wrt to min(l1,l2) total cost will be 2+2+2=6
but cost after sorting list will be swap of ((2,4) and (5,3)) is 2+3=5
so minimum swap to make list identical is min(5,6)=5

```
    //code 
    l1.sort()
    l2.sort(reverse=True)
    sums=0
    for i in range(len(l1)):
            sums+=min(min(l1[i],l2[i]),2*minimum))
    print(sums)
    #print -1 if u get odd count of a key in total (means sums of count of key in both list)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.